How to pass a struct/tuple to viem's `args` field?
I'm trying to call a function that contains a struct as one of its input parameters, however, I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for passing the arguments to the encodeFunctionData util function.
I've tried this:
const mockFacetData = encodeFunctionData({
      abi: diamondCutAbi,
      functionName: "diamondCut",
      args: [
        [mockFacetAddress, 0, ["0x3e6fec04"]],
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      ],
    });

And gotten this error: InvalidAddressError: Address "undefined" is invalid.
Then I tried this:
const mockFacetData = encodeFunctionData({
      abi: diamondCutAbi,
      functionName: "diamondCut",
      args: [
        mockFacetAddress,
        0,
        "0x3e6fec04",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x",
      ],
    });

Which gave this error:
AbiEncodingLengthMismatchError: ABI encoding params/values length mismatch.
Expected length (params): 3
Given length (values): 5


Passing the struct to the args array as an array with a nested object is one valid way of doing this:
const mockFacetData = encodeFunctionData({
      abi: diamondCutAbi,
      functionName: "diamondCut",
      args: [
        [
          {
            facet: mockFacetAddress,
            action: 0,
            selectors: ["0x3e6fec04"],
          },
        ],
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      ],
    });

Please note that the names inside the struct object must match those defined inside the smart contract's struct, e.g. facet, action, and selectors correspond to this struct:
struct FacetCut {
        address facet;
        FacetCutAction action;
        bytes4[] selectors;
    }

